# Annihilator - Product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

Let $M$ be the abelian group, i.e., a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, $M=\mathbb{Z}_{24}\times\mathbb{Z}_{15}\times\mathbb{Z}_{50}$.

I want to find the annihilator $\text{Ann}(M)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

$$$$

$$\text{Ann}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)=\{z\in \mathbb{Z}\mid \forall m\in M, zm=0\}$$

We have that $m\in M : m=(m_1, m_2, m_3)$, where $m_1\in \mathbb{Z}_{24}, m_2\in \mathbb{Z}_{15}, m_3\in \mathbb{Z}_{50}$.

Therefore, $zm=0\Rightarrow (zm_1, zm_2, zm_3)=0$.

$z$ must be the common multiples of $24, 15, 50$, right?

$$$$

I want to find also for the ideal $I=2\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ the $\{m\in M\mid am=0, \forall a\in I\}$ as a product of cyclic groups.

Could you give me some hints how we could do that?

Comment: For the first question  a generator of $\operatorname{Ann}_\mathbf{Z} (M)$ is obviously $\mathrm{lcm}(24,15,50)$.

Comment: Ah ok... I see... @Bernard

Comment: It's not really obvious haha, it took me a minute

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

For you second question, note that if $M=\oplus_k M_k$, then (valid in any commutative ring)
$$(0:I)_M=\bigoplus_k(0:I)_{M_k}$$

Furthermore, $$(0:r)_{\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z}=\begin{cases}d\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z&\text{if}\enspace r\mid n,\enspace n=rd,\\0&\text{if}\enspace r\wedge n=1.\end{cases} $$

Comment: What is the definition of $(0:I)_M$ ?

Comment: It is the set you mentioned. The annihilator of $I$ in $M$.

Comment: Ah ok... Why does it hold that $(0:I)_M=\bigoplus_k(0:I)_{M_k}$ ?

Comment: That's because scalar  multiplication is done componentwise.

Comment: So, we have the following: $$\text{Ann}_M(I)=\{m\in M\mid am=0, \forall a\in I\} \\ =\{m\in \mathbb{Z}_{24}\mid am=0, \forall a\in I\}\times\{m\in \mathbb{Z}_{15}\mid am=0, \forall a\in I\}\times\{m\in \mathbb{Z}_{50}\mid am=0, \forall a\in I\}\\ =\text{Ann}_{\mathbb{Z}_{24}}(I)\times\text{Ann}_{\mathbb{Z}_{15}}(I)\times\text{Ann}_{\mathbb{Z}_{50}}(I)$$ or not? Why is $(0:r)_{\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z}$ defined as above?